# IF statement is not functioning correectly

Tags: php, if-statement

My PHP if statement is not running correctly and I can't see the problem.

Here is the code:

```
$currmonth = date("n");
echo "Current month equals= ", $currmonth, "</br>";  //Displays $currmonth variable
if ($currmonth = 1) {
echo "First Part of If Statement is Working";
}
else {
echo "Second Part of If Statement is Working";
}
```

The currmonth variable displays 3 like it should, since it currently March
The if statement though, ALWAYS displays the "First Part of If Statement is Working" even though it should not be, since the currmonth is not 1.
What am I missing? Am I doing something really stupid?? Please help me before I lose whats left of my mind over this...
Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're doing an assignment inside the `if` statement. It's always going to return true. You want to use the comparison operator (`==`) instead.

```
if ($currmonth == 1) {
    # code...
}
```

You could avoid such errors by making the constant as the first operand:

```
if (1 == $currmonth) {
    # code...
}
```

Here, you can't assign `$currmonth` to `1`, so PHP will complain and throw an error.

Answer (score 1):

Your `if` statement is wrong.
Use `comparison operator (==)` for comparison.
so it should be...

```
if ($currmonth == 1) {
    echo "First Part of If Statement is Working";
}
```